# What does this Kanji mean in this historical book?

Tags: kanji

I was at a bookstore looking at some old books and saw the following weird Kanji between 表 and 主. What is its reading and what does it mean?
[image: Weird Kanji]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book title is [日本外交年表竝主要文書](https://books.google.com/books/about/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E5%A4%96%E4%BA%A4%E5%B9%B4%E8%A1%A8%E7%AB%9D%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%81%E6%96%87%E6%9B%B8.html?id=9lCuAQAACAAJ).

The word is 竝 and it is an alternate/old (異体字) way of writing 並. In the title of this book, it would be an abbreviation for 並びに{ならびに}. I found the following image showing the evolution of the Kanji from [this website](https://okjiten.jp/kanji1039.html) and it feels fairly convincing.

[image: Kanji evolution]

Answer (score 3):

並 originated as a writing abbreviation or stylisation of 竝. which depicts two upright people (立, *vertical, erect, upright*) simultaneously side by side.

The character 竝 represents directly the word 竝{へい}立{りつ} (*to exist simultaneously*).